# Jump height in relation to timeheld of spacebar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This has been asked before, but none of the answers solved my problem because the problem was always slightly different.

I have a character that jumps on spacebar down. I want it to make higher jumps when the spacebar is pressed longer, with a maximum of twice the normal jump height.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && myRB.velocity.y == 0)
    {
        timeHeld = 1;

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && myRB.velocity.y == 0)
    {
        myRB.AddForce(Vector3.up * 20,ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        timeHeld += Time.deltaTime;
        myRB.mass = myRB.mass - timeHeld/10;

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        myRB.mass = 1;

    }
}
```

Since the jump has to happen on keydown (not keyup), I can't increase the force added on jump, because the force is already applied on keydown. Therefore, I was thinking of lowering the mass of my rigidbody.

The above code "works" if I keep holding spacebar: the character jumps (minimum height), lands, jumps again but now a bit higher, etc. But that's not what I'm looking for, obviously.

Comment: add a tag for what language u want an answer in or doesn't matter?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added c# tag.

Comment: U should not look at this as a jump because it is not a jump it is propelling something within certain limits. Is the applied velocity of the character going up constant or variable?

Comment: In other words do u want the jump to go quicker if the spacebar is held longer or not?

Comment: Variable as in the character should go up slowing down, and go down again accelerating. But the jump should be quicker if the spacebar is held down longer.

Comment: Any luck so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done by making a Time frame in which Jumping occurs;
Within this time frame u allow upward forces to be applied by holding space bar down. As soon as you reach either the end of the time frame or the end of the button press; you restrict upward velocity until the character has landed.
Let gravity take its own course after you end the jump.

As for the coding part i suggest you start a co routine when the jump happens.

here is some code to u help you get started;

```
IEnumerator Jumper()
{
    if (maxjumpduration!=jumpduration)
    {
        jumpduration = jumpduration + 0.1f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
    else
    {
        jumpduration = 0;
        StopCoroutine(Jumper());
    }
}
```

As for the fact you want have a regular jump as well; make another time frame in which is decided if the press of space bar is considered either a regular jump or a controlled jump; During that initial time frame in which you are still deciding what kind of jump it is; you execute a short part of the jump until you reach a conclusion and then you send it to the correct method.

I added Some ground work for u but try to finish the code yourself;

```
{
private bool shortjump = false;
private bool checkphase = false;
private bool hitground = false;
private Rigidbody player = new Rigidbody();
private bool jumping = false;
Vector3 sharedjumpforce = new Vector3();
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
        Initialjump();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (jumping)
        {
            shortjump = true;
        }
    }
        if (jumping)
    {
        if (hitground)
        {
            jumping = false;
        }
    }
}

void Initialjump()
{
    if (jumping = false)
    {
        checkphase = true;
        jumping = true;
        player.AddForce(sharedjumpforce);
        Invoke("Standardorcontrolledjump", 0.2f);
    }
}
void Standardorcontrolledjump()
{
    checkphase = false;
    if (shortjump)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm very new to Unity and C#. Any chance you could provide me with more details/code on how to implement this?

Comment: @binoculars i added some code that gives you an idea but you will have to extend it, try to understand the code. I wish you luck

Comment: @binoculars if this answer helped u please accept it. Or do u have further questions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you putting

```
&& myRB.velocity.y == 0
```

You want it to reduce its mass while in air don't you. Assuming that reducing the mass after the initial force has been applied does allow the Rigidbody to go higher, (force of gravity weakens, im not sure if that happens in Unity)

Why don't you try this

```
 void FixedUpdate () {
     // apply force the instant button is pressed. That is only once
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && myRB.velocity.y == 0)
    {
        myRB.AddForce(Vector3.up * 20,ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        timeHeld = 1;

    }
     // keep subtracting from mass while its held
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {

        timeHeld += Time.deltaTime;
        myRB.mass = myRB.mass - timeHeld/10;

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        myRB.mass = 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: If u start changing the mass which is not intended for that purpose; the moment the jump ends he will appear to fall quiet slowly due to the mass change unless u reset it of course. Since gravity is always present even the jump might look deformed if u toy with it during a jump.(since he is using Addforce and not directly manipulating the position otherwise this would be untrue)

Comment: dats why he put `myRB.mass = 1` as soon as the button is lifted i guess, so it should work i suppose

Comment: I know it might work but for example if the game has a pushbackforce applied when you get hit by an enemy; if you get hit while jumping u will fly through the entire game. which is why you should not use such workarounds in my opinion.

Comment: One more thing checking for keys should happen in update never fixed update; just trying to help ;).(u might and i think will at some point experience input loss)